# Jave runtime fatal error

Tags: java, c, dylib

I have a c library XYZ .dylib, which I build using homebrew gcc49. I don't get any problem in make build. 
I have one Java server (I use JDK 1.8_92.) which uses that C Libray .dylib. But when I run that java server I get following error.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000028938, pid=963420, tid=0x00000000023233
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libstdc++.6.dylib+0x26174]  std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&)+0x18
```

I would really appreciate if anyone suggest any solution.

Regards

Comment: Does your c library function correctly if you call it from c? Also, how are you using `std::ostream` in c? Finally, *possible* duplicate of [What is a segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault).

Comment: Please explain in more detail on what you have tried. Also post all relevant code and try to get it down to a minimal test case